# How to convert List to a string and back

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I retrieved a list of users from database, something like

```
List<User> users = <..list of users from db...>
```

**Name, LastName, DateOfBirth //multidimensional array??**

Now I want to store this list as a string and I want be able to reuse it i.e.

```
string strUsers = users.ToArray().ToString();
```

How to recreate a list of users from strUsers?

Is it possible?

Comment: If you have the list of users why do you need to recreate a new list?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666258/linq-to-generic-list?rq=1

Comment: @DarrenDavies if i want to store this temp result set in a DB as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of users and a lot of columns, it would be better to write your own custom converter class.

```
public static class UsersConverter
{
    // Separates user properties.
    private const char UserDataSeparator = ',';

    // Separates users in the list.
    private const char UsersSeparator = ';';

    public static string ConvertListToString(IEnumerable<User> usersList)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Build the users string.
        foreach (User user in usersList)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(user.Name);
            stringBuilder.Append(UserDataSeparator);
            stringBuilder.Append(user.Age);
            stringBuilder.Append(UsersSeparator);
        }

        // Remove trailing separator.
        stringBuilder.Remove(stringBuilder.Length - 1, 1);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public static List<User> ParseStringToList(string usersString)
    {
        // Check that passed argument is not null.
        if (usersString == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("usersString");

        var result = new List<User>();

        string[] userDatas = usersString.Split(UsersSeparator);

        foreach (string[] userData in userDatas.Select(x => x.Split(UserDataSeparator)))
        {
            // Check that user data contains enough arguments.
            if (userData.Length < 2) throw new ArgumentException("Users string contains invalid data.");

            string name = userData[0];
            int age;

            // Try parsing age.
            if (!int.TryParse(userData[1], out age))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Users string contains invalid data.");
            }

            // Add to result list.
            result.Add(new User { Name = name, Age = age });
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You will win performance wise using the StringBuilder to build up your users string. You could also easily expand the converter to take account different separators/additional logic etc.

If you need a more generic solution (to be able to use for any class), you could create a converter which uses reflection to iterate over all the public fields, get/set properties to see what can be extracted as string and later reverse the process to convert your string back to the list.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method, e.g.

```
var joined = string.Join(",", users.Select(u => u.Name));
```

This would give you a single string of user's names separated by ','.

Or for multiple columns:

```
var joined = string.Join(",", 
                 users.Select(u => u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName ));
```

You can reverse the process using [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), e.g.

```
var split = joined.Split( new [] {','} );
```

Comment: and User.Name must not contain commas

Comment: @John you can also split columns with another splitter like `|` so, you can determine on which column you are by iterating over it

Comment: @Phil var split = joined.Split( new [] {','} ); should recreate a list with only one property. You only split rows,not columns. Am I right?

Comment: @john and you should write functionality which will parse User string whith fields, splitted by smth. and assign it into real colums

Comment: @pavko_a I could really use some help on parsing strig within field. This was my biggest problem from the start.

Comment: @john: I'm starting to think you need to serialize your array of users as XML so you can store it and then de-serialize it later.  Search for XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer.  string.Join is ok for creating a simple string, but the resulting string may (probably) be difficult to convert back.

Comment: @Phil you are right, but XML takes to much space when being serialized, so I decided to go for this solution

Comment: @john: ok then you could try JSON which is more compact. Search DataContractJsonSerializer.

Comment: @Phil I need to look it up. I have never used it. What about Shahrooz Jefri answer combindedString = string.Join( ",", myList ); combindedString contains some data in unusual format

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is something that lets you dump all users to a string and get the users back from the string, correct?

I suggest something like this:
Add a method that returns an XElement to the Users type:

```
public XElement GetXElement()
{
    return new XElement("User", new XElement("Name", this.FirstName)) //and so on...
}
```

and then one that decodes the string into a user:

```
static User GetUserFromXElement(string xml)
{
    XElement temp = XElement.Parse(xml);
    User temp = new User();
    foreach (XElement inner in temp.Elements())
    {
        switch inner.Name
        {
            case "Name":
                temp.Name = inner.Value
                break;
            //whatever
        }
    }
}
```

And then do this:

```
public string UsersToElements (List<Users> toWrite)
{
    Stringbuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    XElement root = new XElement("root");
    XDocument temp = new XDocument(root);
    foreach (User user in toWrite)
    {
        root.Append(user.GetXElement());
    }
    temp.Save(sw);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

and this:

```
public List<Users> ElementsToUsers (string xml)
{
    List<Users> usrsList = new List<Users>();
    XDocument temp = XDocument.Load(xml);
    foreach (XElement e in XDocument.Root.Elements())
    {
        usrsList.Append(Users.GetUserFromXElement(e));
    }
    return usrsList;
}
```

JSON solution (using JSON.NET)

```
public JObject GetJObject()
{
return new JObject("user", new JProperty("name", this.FirstName)); //so on
}

static User GetUserFromJObject(string json)
{
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
return new User() { FirstName = (string)obj["user"]["name"] }; //so on
}

public string UsersToElements (List<Users> users)
{    
   JObject root = new JObject(from usr in users select new JAttribute("user", usr.GetJObject());
   return root.ToString();
}

public List<users> ElementsToUsers(string json)
{
List<Users> users = new List<Users>();
JObject temp = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (JObject o in (JEnumerable<JObject>)temp.Children())
{
users.Add(Users.GetUserFromJObject(o.ToString());
}
return users;
}
```

I have no idea if ths works :/ (well the XML I know it does, not so sure about the JSON)

Comment: interesting approach, but I do not want to use xml. i believe it would take to much space, as I want to store temp results as a string in db.

Comment: JSON would be a better approach then. Before I build lots of (maybe useless) JSON code, do you want JSON?

Comment: Json is definitely an option

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
string combindedString = string.Join( ",", myList );

var Array = combindedString.Split( new [] {','} );
```

Comment: How to get it from Array to List<User>?